CISCO UCSC-C220-M4S loud fan, power profile not respected
I recently purchased a used Cisco UCSC-C220-M4S at a reasonable price, which included a Tesla GPU. However, I discovered that the GPU model is not officially supported. Although it can still be installed and utilized, it doesn't report its temperature to the motherboard. This situation causes the server to activate a protective measure, using a balanced power model instead of a low-power one. While I am not concerned about the increase in power consumption, the balanced setting causes the fans to spin faster, generating significant noise.
I want to maintain a GPU for creating a Windows VM, what are my options? Is it feasible to connect the GPU to an external GPU enclosure to avoid the server's protective response, should I replace the fans with quieter ones, or is purchasing a new, supported GPU a better solution?
I am uncertain if using an eGPU would address the issue or if its cost compared to a supported GPU would be justified. I have not been able to find a list of GPUs supported by this server model.
Is it advisable to keep the GPU inside the server and simply replace the fans with quieter ones?
Lastly, is a GPU necessary for creating a Windows VM ?
Thank you for your guidance.

This post is coming from serverfault where I learned it was meant for superuser.
Since I originally posted this question I installed a windows VM without a GPU and it look like working for now (installation went well, didn't had the chance to test it yet). I also removed the GPU and fan when quieter. Since I want to run plex it would be awesome to put a gpu back in it, so the question still relevant.
Thank you.
